# Javascript - swap image on click or rollover

Tags: javascript, image, rollover

I know how to do this in jquery but i am trying to do the below in pure old school javascript.  Can someone help:

```
$(".thumbnail").click(function() {
    $("#mainImage").attr("src", $(this).attr("src"));
});
```

My ultimate goal is to click on a thumbnail and have the main image change but I need to do it in javascript (no jquery).  I know this sounds pretty simple but I cannot figure it out.  thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There are so many things that jQuery gives you automatically that it's difficult to give you an answer that will do everything that your jQuery code does.  Here is a simple example that will find every image with a class of `thumbnail` and set its `onclick` property to an event handler that performs an image swap.

```
onload = function () {
    var bigImg = document.getElementById("mainImage");
    for (var i = 0; i < document.images.length; i++) {
        var img = document.images[i];
        if (/\bthumbnail\b/.test(img.className) {
            img.onclick = thumbnailHandler;
        }
    }
    function thumbnailHandler(e) {
        bigImg.src = this.src;
    }
};
```

If you don't have to support IE7, you can simplify it slightly by using `document.querySelectorAll()`:

```
onload = function () {
    var bigImg = document.getElementById("mainImage");
    var thumbs = document.querySelectorAll(".thumbnail");
    for (var i = 0; i < thumbs.length; i++) {
        thumbs[i].onclick = thumbnailHandler;
    }
    function thumbnailHandler(e) {
        bigImg.src = this.src;
    }
};
```

As an aside, I don't understand why you are setting the source of the main image to be the source of the thumbnail.  Are you loading the full image into the thumbnail?  That can be a lot to download and can quickly increase the memory footprint of your page.

Answer (score 0):

Event delegation is probably the easiest way:

```
function expandThumbnail(e) {
    if(~(' ' + e.target.className + ' ').indexOf(' thumbnail ')) {
        document.getElementById('mainImage').src = e.target.src;
    }
}

if(document.addEventListener) {
    document.addEventListener('click', expandThumbnail, false);
} else {
    document.attachEvent('onclick', function() {
        expandThumbnail({
            target: event.srcElement
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: @user982853: Could you be a little more specific about what's not working? Is there an error?

Comment: sorry, there is no error but when i click the thumb it doesn't chamber the main.

Comment: @user982853: Are you calling `stopPropagation()` anywhere else?

Comment: is there a way to do it inline? instead of function.

Comment: @user982853: Yes, but it involves code duplication, so don't do it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right, you have a thumbnail image displayed, let's say '1thumb.png', of an associated image, let's say '1.png', and when you click this thumbnail image you want to change the src attribute of a main image, let's say with id='mainimg', to show the '1.png' image associated to the thumbnail instead of whatever it's showing. I tried this and it works:

Inside your `<header>`:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function myHandler(source){
    document.getElementById('mainimg').src=source;
}
</script>
...
```

Your thumbnail code:

```
<img src='1thumb.png' onclick="myHandler('1.png')"/>
```

or, for rollover triggering:

```
<img src='1thumb.png' onmouseover="myHandler('1.png')"/>
```

Check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/d7Q27/7/

Comment: That's true, but in this case it's really simple this way. Less code, less trouble, right?

Comment: Not really. The entire premise implies that there are multiple images here. What if you changed the ID of the large image container? You have to change it in every single handler. That, and it's just not pretty, and doesn't separate nicely either (multiple handlers, anyone?)

Comment: The `javascript:` doesn't belong in `on*` attributes, only in `href`s.